# Module source is undefined following Webpack 5 Loader Guide

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

I'm trying to follow the guide to [Writing a Loader](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/) using Webpack 5.2.0.  At the bottom of the page we are guided through a simple Jest test sample.  The Jest test checks that the first module object `source` property is the source that our loader generated.  I can verify that my Webpack compiler step generated a module with a `name` property of `./example.txt`.  But the `source` property is always `'undefined'`.  This is despite `stats.hasErrors()` returning false.

I'm new to Webpack loader development and I'm not sure what I'm missing.  The [module structure](https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/#module-objects) description indicates this property should contain my module source if it was successful.

Have others successfully completed this scenario with a recent verison of Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of googling i [found](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10534#issuecomment-648460082) that for webpack@5 you need to pass additional options to have `source` field in output.

```js
stats.toJson({
  source: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some context to this answer, in order to make the Webpack5 [Writing a Loader, Testing Section](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#testing) work (as it was 10/31/2020), adjust the following.  With Lesha's suggestion above, the `output` line in `test/loader.test.js` should read

```
const output = stats.toJson({source: true}).modules[0].source;
```

That solves the missing `source` attribute problem.  The Jest test will still fail unless you created the `example.txt` without a newline on the end.  Either ensure there is no line ending or change your `expect` clause to the following:

```
expect(output).toBe('export default "Hey Alice!\\n"');
```

Comment: I added a pull request to correct this.  I'll update this post if it is accepted.  https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/4114.

Comment: Pull request has been merged.